# To execute or not execute Jquery Script Based On Form Selection

Tags: jquery

SchoolI have a jquery script that validates an email field in my form. This script makes sure the form accepts only email addresses ending with a certain domain. However, I have another field in my form where a user identified if they are staff, faculty, or other. If they choose other, I want to forego the email validation and let the user enter any valid email address. Here is some of my relevant code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
<script>
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        }, "<span class='error2'>You must use your School email address.</span>"
);
 $().ready(function() {
  // validate the comment form when it is submitted

  // validate signup form on keyup and submit
  $("#helpdeskform").validate({
   rules: {
    email: {
     required: true,
     email: true,
              regex: '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@domain.edu|student.domain.edu+$'
    },
    agree: "required"
   },
   messages: {
    email: {
             required: "Please enter a valid email address",
          },
    agree: "Please accept our policy"
   }
  });

</script>
```

```html
<form method="post" id="helpdeskform" name="helpdeskform" action="tracking.injector2.php">
  
          <table width="760" border="0" style="margin: 0 20px 0 20px;">
    
               
               
          <tr>
            <td><label for="user">Choose One:</label></td>
            <td>
              <select name="user" id="user">
                <option value="student">Student</option>
                <option value="staff">Staff</option>
                <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select></td>
           
          </tr>
          </table>
<input type="submit" name= 'add' value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a listener on the submit event of the form, then make the verifications you need and if they went ok, then let the form submit itself or interrup the submission.

```
$('#helpdeskform').submit(function() {
    if($('#user').val() != 'other') {
        //Invalidate form and then cancel the submit
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I may not have been clear. In reality the form is much larger than above, I only inluded the relevant piece. Therefore, I do not want to cancel submission of the form entirely. ALL I want to to is disregard therule that requires email to have a certain domain if other is chosen in the firm